# can't control pianobar after using echo

Tags: 12.04, bash, pianobar

I have a script that starts pianobar (pandora player) and autoloads into tty2 after booting.
I'm running Ubuntu Precise 12.04.

it's a pretty simple script:

```
    #!bin/bash
    sleep 5
    echo "2" | pianobar
```

This works, it selects station 2 and begins playing... but when I try to type in commands it doesn't work (like pushing "p" for pause.) It'll show the letter for a second, then hide it. If I try to exit with ctrl+z it just sits there and I can't use it at all.

If I run this it works fine but doesn't auto-select the second station:

```
    #!bin/bash
    sleep 5
    pianobar
```

Is there anyway to write this so it will automatically input "2" and then allow me to control from there?
Or am I stuck with having to select 2 every time I boot up?

EDIT:

I modified it to this:

```
    #!bin/bash
    sleep 5
    { echo 2 ; cat ; } | pianobar
```

and it does the exact same thing as just "echo 2 | pianobar"

"*Isn't there an option to pianobar to start with a default station*"

I would of thought so, but I can't find a command for a default setting when I do "man pianobar"

When I open the program, it does a login and then the program starts with "Select station:"
I'd like for it to automatically go into the 2nd station.

Answer (score 0):

What happens is that you link the stdout of `echo` with the stdin of `pianobar`, but then echo exits and the stream is gone. Try that:

```
{ echo 2 ; cat ; } | pianobar
```

My main question, however, would be -- what are you trying to achieve? Why not start just the pianobar? Isn't there an option to pianobar to start with a default station, if that's the problem?